# Why if integer is always True

Tags: python

I am a bit confused with if/else statement. Why the code always prints True while it should be False.

I have tried with different variables like `i =10`, `i = 'a'`, `i = 25`. And it will be False if `i=[]`

This is my code:

`i =1
if i:
    print True
else:
    print False`

Comment: its false for 0. isn't it nice to be able to check if a number is non zero, or a string non empty, and so on? :)

Comment: Why do you think it should be `False` on any of these examples?

Comment: Because as far as I knew, If i: is equal to if i==1.Isn't it?

Comment: No, it isnt. Here's some [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). So (tl;dr its more close to `bool(i)` which translates to `i !=0` for ints. Different languages have different conventions, and you have to be careful assuming things.

Answer (score -1):

In your code you say `if I: True`. But your not comparing it to anything.  You need a comparison operator. Like `if i == 1` otherwise the if statement will just be true IF I has a value by default

Comment: "Not comparing it to anything" is incorrect. In a line `if x:`, *x itself* is evaluated as a Truthy/Falsy value, and so is equivalent to `if bool(x) == True`.